# integrate a .net application with alfresco using cmis

Tags: .net, alfresco, cmis, dotcmis

How to integrate a .net application with alfresco ? 
How cam cmis be used to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Chemistry DotCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html) to perform perform CMIS requests from your .net code. The API is very similar to the Java OpenCMIS API, so you can then find a tutorial on using OpenCMIS to talk to Alfresco and do largely the same thing with DotCMIS.

If you're new to CMIS, then [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org) provides a [very handy overview](http://chemistry.apache.org/project/cmis.html) on their site.

Answer (score 0):

The example at http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/remote-api/source/sample/WcfCmisTest/ should get you started with C# , CMIS and Alfresco.